# How to join 2 tables when it has different values in the column

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I have 2 tables as follows.

[image]

Need to join these 2 tables to get below table

[image]

I am trying different joins but not getting expected results. Could you please help me to get the desired table.

Really appreciate your help.

Thanks...

Comment: You can UNION ALL the tables, and GROUP BY the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hope*** this solution can help you, (I am used **SQL_Server** syntax)

```
SELECT isnull(date1,date2) as Date3, ISNULL(RM, 0 ),ISNULL(KM, 0 )
FROM table1 
FULL JOIN table2 
ON table1.Date1 = table2.Date2
order by Date3;
```

**[RESULT]:**

[image]

**[EDIT]:**
Live demo

> ```
> create table Table1 (DATE1 date, RM int);
>
> INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('1/4/2020' , 1);
> INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('2/1/2020' , 4);
> INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('2/10/2020' , 4);
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```

3 rows affected

> 

> ```
> create table Table2 (DATE2 date, KM int);
>
> INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('2/2/2020' , 1);
> INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('2/10/2020' , 3);
> INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('3/5/2020' , 2);
> GO
> ```

3 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from Table1;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> DATE1      | RM
> :--------- | -:
> 2020-01-04 |  1
> 2020-02-01 |  4
> 2020-02-10 |  4
> ```

> ```
> select * from Table2;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> DATE2      | KM
> :--------- | -:
> 2020-02-02 |  1
> 2020-02-10 |  3
> 2020-03-05 |  2
> ```

> ```
> SELECT isnull(date1,date2) as Date3, ISNULL(RM, 0 ),ISNULL(KM, 0 )
> FROM table1 
> FULL JOIN table2 
> ON table1.Date1 = table2.Date2
> order by Date3;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Date3      | (No column name) | (No column name)
> :--------- | ---------------: | ---------------:
> 2020-01-04 |                1 |                0
> 2020-02-01 |                4 |                0
> 2020-02-02 |                0 |                1
> 2020-02-10 |                4 |                3
> 2020-03-05 |                0 |                2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f87d98a279896c016141baa6c2021c47)*

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your answer gave me a through and implemented same with case statement. Ex. case when dt1 is null then dt2 else dt1 end.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know scala but in pyspark you can do the following:

```
df1.join(df2, 'DATE', 'full').fillna(0)
```

Essentially you do a full join and fill all the NULLs with 0.

For Hive SQL I guess it would be something like

```
SELECT Date, 
       CASE WHEN (table1.RM IS NOT NULL) THEN table1.RM ELSE 0 END AS RM, 
       CASE WHEN (table2.KM IS NOT NULL) THEN table2.KM ELSE 0 END AS KM
FROM table1 
FULL JOIN table2 
ON table1.Date = table2.Date
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. We are using hive and need to develop query in hive.

Answer (score 1):

I have created two initial dataframe named as df_rm, df_km as a source for your data.

df_rm looks like this:

```
+---------+---+
|     date| rm|
+---------+---+
| 1/4/2020|  1|
| 2/1/2020|  4|
|2/10/2020|  4|
+---------+---+
```

df_km:

```
+---------+---+
|     date| km|
+---------+---+
| 2/2/2020|  1|
|2/10/2020|  3|
| 3/5/2020|  2|
+---------+---+
```

Now, first we can do outer join then replace the null values with some values, in this case 0.

```
df_km.join(right = df_rm, Seq("date"),joinType = "outer")
      .withColumn("rm",when(col("rm").isNull,0).otherwise(col("rm")))
      .withColumn("km",when(col("km").isNull,0).otherwise(col("km")))
      .show()
```

Which outputs like this:

```
+---------+---+---+
|     date| km| rm|
+---------+---+---+
| 3/5/2020|  2|  0|
| 2/2/2020|  1|  0|
| 2/1/2020|  0|  4|
| 1/4/2020|  0|  1|
|2/10/2020|  3|  4|
+---------+---+---+
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and I need to implement this in Hive. Finally I got it and thank you for your response.